# Why is the IF statement inside my For Loop never meeting its condition?

Tags: java

I have tried everything and I just cannot see why I am getting this issue. Here is the code I am using:

```
        for( int i=0; i< objarray.size();i++)
        {
            //Toast shows values
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), goingToId+""+objarray.get(i).getid(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (goingToId == objarray.get(i).getid())
            {
                //This Toast NEVER shows
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside the if statement",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                glat = objarray.get(i).getlat();
                glon = objarray.get(i).getlon();
                loc = new Location("dummyprovider");
                loc.setLatitude(glat);
                loc.setLongitude(glon);
            }   
        }
```

Both of the values being compared are strings. In the for loop, the two values are output in toasts and i can clearly see when the two are the same value, but the for loop always finishes without ever entering the IF statement, or the IF statement never meets its condition, but I don't know why.

I do this kind of thing all the time in C# and it always works, can anyone see why this would not be working in Android? I understand there is not much information to go on in my post, but you can trust me when I say that they values do eventually match while iterating through the for loop. Any advice would be appreciated as I am clueless.

Comment: I guess that's strings you are comparing ?

Comment: goingToId is String..?

Comment: its possible that you don't see this toast because one of the next iteration is hiding it

Comment: @njzk2 `getid());` hopefully returns an int

Comment: I agree with @MarkoNiciforovic, I have been bitten by the == versus .Equals(x) in java.  Use .Equals.  Not sure if that fixes you problem as it is hard from the code sample to see what you are comparing.

Comment: Sorry guys I forgot to say that the data types are strings! Sorry!

Comment: @mr.VVoo : just so you know : toast are enqueued and displayed one after the other unless canceled in the mean time.

Comment: @njzk2: i already had the behavior i described in one of my apps, they were displayed in parallel and not after another.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end of your if statement:

```
 if (goingToId.equals(objarray.get(i).getid()))
```

Comment: Oh my god. I am almost crying with happiness, this fixed it! All this time and it was something as simple as this! :/ Thank you so much, I was literally smashing my computer! Thank you!

Comment: I will just add that "==" with `String` comparison in Java compares a reference to the object whereas `var.equals("string")` compares there values

Comment: Good man for the explaining code Magic!! I swear this was driving me nuts! :) I will accept the answer when it allows me in 6 minutes! Thank you!!

Comment: Glad we could help. That one gets people all the time :)

Comment: It wont get me again that's for sure! :) Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

```
if (goingToId == objarray.get(i).getid()); //<<<<
```

remove semicon from end of if condition

Comment: I removed it, it was there from when I was trying while loops instead, but even before the semi colon was there it still did not work, but good job noticing it! :)

Comment: @deucalion0 : it still not working make sure u are comparing integer using `==` if u are comparing Strings then use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 2):

**Remove the semicolon.**

```
if (goingToId == objarray.get(i).getid());
```

When you write the semicolon at the end of `if` statement then control not goes inside it then inside the `if` become Unrechable Code.

Learn difference between `equals` and `==`.

Difference between == and equals() method.

== is used to compare the reference. and equals method check the content of string variable.

Example.

First example

```
String s1 = "FirstString";
String s2 = "FirstString";

if(s1 == s2) {
   //This condition matched true because java don't make separate object for these two string. Both strings point to same reference.
}
```

Second example

```
String s1= "FirstString";
String s2 = new String("FirstString");

if(s1.equals(s2)) {
 //This condition true because same content.
}

if(s1 == s2) {
 //This condition will be false because in this java allocate separate reference for both of them
}
```

Conclusion: Java check whether string exist or not. If we create the object of second string using new and have different content then its creates object and assign different reference and In case of If we don't create the object using new and have same content then its assign the same reference as first string contain.